# How to design an Android indoor map of a building?

Tags: android, indoor-positioning-system

I want to design an Android application which can help students and others navigate their way around a particular building(with one floor) showing walking directions to classrooms.

I need help with it.

Comment: Make PDF with a blueprint of the building and show it in a `WebView`.

Comment: Did you find the solution? Could you please to share. Thank you so much

Answer (score 10):

This is the kind of project you normally develop for your thesis. It is much larger and more complex of what it can look at a first glance.

Googling around you will find a lot of BCS and master thesis on this topic. Read them and you will find almost all the information you need to develop your own system.

As a starting point you can use redpin: http://redpin.org/ .

While Google Maps can actually support indoor mapping and navigation, most likely it is not what you are looking for. If you want to use you own algorithm form routing, you cannot use Google Maps.

Have a look at the Open Source Routing Machine (OSRM): http://project-osrm.org/ .

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the google page for uploading and making an indoor map.](http://support.google.com/gmm/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1685896&topic=1685871&ctx=topic)

Comment: thanks but i want to use A*algorithm in finding the route.

Comment: i am using google maps. i deployed it in an android emulator with an API key.i am struggling in creating a node since it is indoor.How do i get a node using WIFI which is used indoor? and also Android Indoor application for ROUTE SEARCH.

Comment: i have problem in a creating a ROUTE SEARCH IN Android for an indooor path.